# House History for demolished property

Tags: england, building

I am researching the history of demolished properties and the reasons why they were demolished. For example, they may have been unfit for occupancy.

Where can I find information on a property in Grove Lane, Hemsworth and also its most recent occupants?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take a moment to look at the [help], especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  I have assumed that you are referring to Hemsworth in West Yorkshire - if this is NOT the case, please edit your question to put in the location you are doing research in.  The answers to your question will vary greatly depending on research location.  Your question can also be improved by showing us what research you have already done. If you have  questions about how the site works, you can post them on our companion [meta].

Answer (score 1):

The local electoral registers should show who was living there over the years. The relevant local council for Hemsworth should be able to advise where old registers are stored. (They may not be on-line). The County Record office may have them.